# What's the SE policy/attitude on directing users to a site like codementor.io

Tags: discussion

I use codementor.io and find it's a great resource for users who like/need 1:1 guidance and assistance on programming and related topics.

The site is not free as users (mentees) pay their mentors for their time.

Full disclosure, I am a mentor on the site. However, I would never link to myself directly. I just believe in the education model.

I often see users ask very broad 'recommendation' type questions on SE and think that these users may find the 1:1 guidance a real benefit.

I want to know what the SE community thinks about recommending sites like these to users. Is it perfectly acceptable? only in certain situations? or is extremely frowned upon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommendation questions should simply be closed on most sites (the obvious exceptions being the [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sites).

Overly broad is also a reason for closure.

We don't allow these questions as they are generally not useful to others, and likely not even to the asker as they simply haven't thought about or specified their problem sufficiently for it to be answerable. Attempts to answer often end up in the question morphing as the asker tries to use the various answers to refine their question into the one they realise they meant to ask in the first place.

Answering them with something that only consists of a link to **any** off-site resource is not acceptable.

Comment: Right, this would be of little help to any other users. Excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

There's nearly no situation where recommending an external resource is a correct answer.  External resources can go down, or change their model.

Good/great answers are focused, self contained, and don't just help the user but also the *next* person with the same problem.

If there's a site that allows for *website* or *resource* recommendations, maybe. As is, there's nothing close.

I've seen a *few* cases where someone's mentioned sites like that here, in comments, but broadly I suspect the answer is "no".

Comment: Fair enough, all good points.

Comment: Answers that explain why and how a given external tool (library, program) can be used to solve the particular problem are fine and can be excellent. For example, on SO, recommending a particular function within a given third-party library. Answers that summarize a linked resource giving the answer that is too long to embed or of a radically different nature from text (video, audio, etc) are usually acceptable as well.

Comment: It's really only answers that recommend something *that can be used in the process of discovering the final answer* that are problematic the way you describe. But those are delete-worthy even if they contain no external links at all: an answer that is nothing more than "here are the steps to determine the root cause of your problem so you can update the question" isn't an answer at all, but a comment.

Comment: Well, that's a different kettle of fish in my experience. Of course, I understand different perspectives for people from different sites, and the two sites I have (historically or currently moderated) have pretty strict/detailed rules specific to us about recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If you "*want to know what the SE community thinks about recommending sites like these to users*" (as in your question), you could also use what's called "Community promotion ads" on those SE sites that still / already use them.

Such as the [currently active version of it on Drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516). Checkout this link (or find a similar one on an SE site you use) if you're not familiar with such ads, to understand the rules of the game, and also see some real world samples.

Specific to the site you mentioned, it *might* not be a good fit for such ads, though I bet there might be *certain situations* (as in your question) where it could be a perfect fit though.